# Does CameraKit recompress images?

Tags: android, camera, android-camera, jpeg

There is a `byte[]` that seems to be an out-of-camera JPEG in `CameraView@captureImage` (it has EXIF, and of the same size as an images captured by the default camera). That `byte[]` is then passed to a `PostProcessor`, which outputs a JPEG that is almost 3 times larger than the initial `byte[]` on my device (Mi 5 MIUI 9.5.3.0). Why does CameraKit recompress the image? Can it be avoided? The final function that converts the image is a native method, I can't debug it.

I admit that this could be a device-specific problem, as I read somewhere that the DNG "path" of the Mi 5 is "broken", maybe the normal output is "broken" too. In that case, what is the `byte[]` that will be passed to `PostProcessor`, uncompressed bitmap or even DNG (unlikely)? I want to at least know this piece of information :)

Here's the link to the 2 captured images. The larger (sample...) one is the CameraKit output, the smaller one (test.jpg) is the dump of the initial `byte[]` right before it is passed into a `PostProcessor`.
[Images](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1NOGTl4cMr8zfDM5C5qplf0KASd5QOlNh)

Thanks for your reply!

PS: here is the confusing block of code

[image: <code>byte[]</code> JPEG is passed into a <code>PostProcessor</code>]

Furthermore, the final JPEG output of CameraKit (the larger file) lacks EXIF.

Comment: Why are you passing that byte [] to a post processor?

Comment: So you mean that the file size is larger. But the resolution is the same?

Comment: Yes, and a further reduce in quality. They coded it like that!

Comment: Please answer all questions.

Comment: Yes, the resolution doesn't change between the 2 images. I included samples in the post.

Comment: You still did not answer all questions.

Comment: 1. That's their code, I don't know why they pass it into a `PostProcessor`

Comment: 2. The resolution is the same

Comment: I mean that's the library code, I don't follow any guide to write those lines, I just use them

Comment: If you have a jpg file and convert it to a bitmap using BitmapFactory.loadFile and then compress the bitmap to a jpg file again you will end up with a different file size too.

Comment: Of course :) And the quality is reduced, and the performance is wasted too. But I want to at least know why they do this, and how to avoid it, before resorting to the last solution - rewrite those line to return the original JPEG

Comment: Why do they pass the aray to the post processor? If you dont wanna use that code then remove it. I dont understand the fuss.

Comment: Yes, that's the last solution. However, I want to make sure the initial `byte[]` array is always a valid JPEG before return it, because it could be a device-specific problem. What if other phones return a TIFF or something? For now I can't predict! CameraKit is a grown up library, there has to be some reasons they do redundant compress.